# How using a derived property in HQL where clause

Tags: hibernate, hql

i have an entity like this:

```
public class Account{
    private String code;
    @ManyToOne
    private Account ledgerAccount;


    public String getCode(){
        return code;
    }

    public String getFullCode(){
        return ledgerAccount.getCode()+code;
    }
}
```

So, `fullCode` is a derived property, i want to use it in my hql queries, how can i achive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a property called `fullCode` in your model and annotate it like this:

> @Formula("ledgerAccount.code+code")
>   private String fullCode;

and change your `getFullCode()` method to:

```
public String getFullCode() {
    return fullCode;
}
```

And then in your HQL:

```
select * from Account where fullCode = ?
```

If you haven't already, check [this page](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_derived_properties_performance_and) for more examples.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, using this formula it's work: @Formula("(select a.code||code from Account a where a.id=ledgeraccount_id)")